# MySQL 8 slow query issue

Tags: mysql-8.0, mysql-slow-query-log

My MySQL 8 conf as below :

```
[mysqld]
slow_query_log = ON
long_query_time = 5
log_slow_admin_statements = 1
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1
```

But when I got slow query log in my table that will show :
[image]

The query time do not match long_query_time (5s)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just found out why I recommend turning this off

```
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 0
```

When a tiny table is accessed without an index, it will run fast enough that you should not care, and it should not clutter the log.

I also recommend a much lower value for this

```
long_query_time = 1
```

`pt-query-digest` is a good tool for summarizing the data, especially if the log is written to a FILE.